# Add external javascript to post template

Tags: plugins, functions, javascript

I want to add external JavaScript link in the custom post template. I am adding the below function in the child theme. But the external link is not loaded in the custom post theme.
Am I doing something wrong ? TIA

```
function temp_enqueue_scripts() {
        if ( 'custom-template.php' == get_page_template() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script('script0', 'lib/myscript.js', array('jquery'));
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'temp_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: You should use [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) and make sure the script URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add The following code (in your theme's functions.php) will register your script, and set jQuery as a dependency. So when you enqueue it, jQuery will also be enqueued.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
   // register your script location, dependencies and version
   wp_register_script('my_custom_script',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
       array('jquery'),
       '1.0' );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

You can then enqueue your script one of two ways. In your theme's functions.php you can use the template_include filter the get the template being used using is_page_template()

```
function my_load_script_for_template( $template ){
     if(is_page_template('my-template.php'))
        wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_script');

return $template;
}
 add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_load_script_for_template', 1000 );
```